# Laravel Caching not storing database result array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to cache database query as given below (Laravel 5.7):

```
Cache::remember('footer_pages', 180, function () {
    DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'title')->where(array('status' => 'Published', 'menu_position' => 'Footer'))->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')->get();
});
```

But Cache is empty. Please help me find what mistake I did.

Comment: do `return DB::table...`. The function `remember` will cache the result of the callback

Comment: thanks a lot. plz post is as answrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remember function will store the result of the callback in the cache if a callback is provided.

That means you need to make your callback return the result you want stored:

```
Cache::remember('footer_pages', 180, function () {
    return DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'title')->where(array('status' => 'Published', 'menu_position' => 'Footer'))->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')->get();
});
```